# Stapelia problems?

Tags: succulents

I have a small collection of succulents. 5 years ago I brought home a stapelia that never bloomed. Last year it started to change colors. It grows green at first but eventually changes to this brownish color. The plant keeps growing. Is there any problem with it? It doesnt look healthy. Thank you[image]

Comment: Where does the plant reside? The reddening can be due to too much sun. Is it overexposed to sun?

Comment: It sits all year in a west facing window with direct sunlight. Should I just move it to a more shadowy place?

Comment: I am no expert to be honest, but when my cacti start going red, I move them to a less sunny place and they become green again in the course of several months. And from the looks of your plant it's not such a sun lover. So I'd say yes.

Comment: Also related: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/why-is-my-cactus-purple

Comment: What species of Stapelia is it? It doesn't look like one of the most common kinds.

Comment: I'd be careful about watering (I believe they don't want very much, especially in winter where they might not want any at all), and make sure the pH is right. I think it might need a more alkaline soil. An eastern windowsill in zone 6 in a glazed ceramic pot shaped like a boat worked great for my Grandma's Stapelia (but it was a different species); not sure about western windows.